# Django TypeError

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Создал такие модели:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    teacher = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Teacher)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

при попытке добавить в Subject в админке пишет:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки, потому что без стека непонятно, где она возникла

Comment: А также сообщите версию Python и версию Django

Comment: @andreymal Django 2.1.2, Python 3.6.2

Comment: @andreymal log: http://dpaste.com/3GWTC6P